# How to convert/cast NSNumber to Int64?

Tags: swift

Just like the title says. I had to store `Int64` in `NSUserDefaults` and the only way I found to do that was storing it as `NSNumber` like

```
NSNumber(longLong: someInt64)
```

but I don't know how to convert it back to Int64.

Comment: A little bit of [reading the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSNumber/longLongValue) can go a long way.

Comment: What part don't you understand?  Reading documentation is a crucial part of being a developer, so if there's something you're not understanding, I'd love to help you figure it out (which you'll realize will save you time in the long run).

Comment: @TimSim, I added a longer writeup about `NSNumber` and its history.

Comment: @TimSim: It looks like you don't have a question, but you just have to learn the basics about Objective-C, Swift, Cocoa, and UIKit. Find a good book and read it.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yeah, good advice, but not for me. I just can't follow textbooks, I could read a paragraph 20 times and not understand it. It would take me a year to read a programming book

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Use the `int64Value` property of `NSNumber` to retrieve the `Int64` value:

```
let someInt64: Int64 = 314

let n = NSNumber(value: someInt64)

let m = n.int64Value  // m is an `Int64`
```

---

**Long Answer**

`NSNumber` is unlike primitive types such as `Int` and `Double`.  `NSNumber` is a **class** that comes from *Foundation*, which was designed around Objective-C and its limitations.  `NSNumber` serves as an object wrapper for primitive types (such as `Int`, `Double`, and `Bool`) which are not objects.

In Objective-C, objects are stored in `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`, but these can only hold objects (i.e. instances of classes).  Primitive types such as `Int`, `Double`, and `Bool` are not objects.  The designers of Objective-C had a problem; it wouldn't be very useful if you couldn't put integers or doubles in arrays and dictionaries.  The solution was to wrap these primitive types in a class called `NSNumber`.

Originally in Objective-C, `NSNumbers` were created with constructors such as:

```
// Objective-C
NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: 3.14];
NSNumber *b = [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES];
```

When *Modern Objective-C* features were added, it became possible to create them more simply:

```
// Modern Objective-C
NSNumber *n = @3.14;
NSNumber *b = @YES;
```

Once you have an `NSNumber`, you can extract the contained value by calling the appropriate property:

```
// Objective-C
double d = [n doubleValue];     // method call notation
double d = n.doubleValue;       // dot notation

// Swift
let d = n.doubleValue
```

Swift has the ability of creating `NSNumber` on the fly when assigning a primitive type (`Int`, `Double`, `Bool`, etc.) to a variable of type `NSNumber`.  This was done to make it easy to call `Cocoa` and `Cocoa Touch` APIs from Swift without having to explicitly wrap primitive types (which would have been painful).

```
// In Swift
let n: NSNumber = 3.14    // No need to do let n = NSNumber(double: 3.14)

let a = NSMutableArray()
a.addObject(3.14)         // No need for a.addObject(NSNumber(double: 3.14))
a.addObject(true)         // No need for a.addObject(NSNumber(bool: true))
```

The weird thing about `NSNumber` is that you can put in one type and retrieve another:

```
// In Swift
let n: NSNumber = 3.14
let truth = n.boolValue
print(truth)   // "true"
```

so it is up to the program to keep track of what is in there.

So, if you have an `NSNumber` and want the value contained within as an `Int64`, you need to access it with the `int64Value` property:

```
let n = NSNumber(value: someInt64)
let m = n.int64Value  // m is an `Int64`
```

Comment: Thanks man, they should get you to write the docs. The thing is now that I've read your explanation, I can also understand that part of the official docs. What confused me and threw me off in this case was that I could do `Double(someNSNumber)` or `Int(someNSNumber)` but not `Int64(someNSNumber)`.

Comment: 'longLongValue' has been renamed to 'int64Value'

Comment: how you do `let m = n.int64Value` in Objective-C ? 
say you have NSNumber in Objective-C code and you want to covert it to a Int64 in Swift code.

Comment: Note, in objective-c it's `longLongValue` not `int64Value`

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 3**

An example for storing and retrieving the properties for milliseconds. Can be used for any `Int64` object :

```
 fileprivate static let TIME = "TIME"
 public static var time: Int64 {
        get {
            if let obj = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: TIME), let t = obj as? NSNumber {
                return t.int64Value
            }
                return Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0)
        }
        set(v) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(NSNumber(value: v), forKey: TIME)
        }
    }
```